# Using 'with' statement in python to auto-close a pyplot.figure

Tags: python, plot, figure, with-statement

I want to reformat a close-intensive code like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
do some plotting
plt.close(fig)
```

to

```
with plt.figure() as fig:
  do some plotting
```

for elegancy.

But it looks like that **plt.figure** object does not have **__enter__()** and **__exit__()** methods, from its documentation. Is there any other built-in approach I can use to support feature like that?

Comment: No, but yould implement your own context handler.

Comment: I think you're looking for [contextlib.closing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing).

Comment: @PaulM. I think it's a little bit different. When you close a figure, it's not calling `fig.close()`, but instead, `pyplot.close(fig)`

Comment: But thanks, the contextlib is exactly what I need. :)

Comment: @cyfex Oops, glad it's somewhat helpful, though!